# How do I resize the PopUpMenuItems?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, material-design

I have a `PopUpMenuButton` with items, I have no idea how to resize the whole box that opens with the items, I tried putting the `ListTile` into a `SizedBox` but it doesn't change the size. Also how do I retain its aspect ratio while doing so?

I need to make this pop up smaller:

[image]

```
Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: PopupMenuButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 4/1,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: SizedBox(
                              height: 1,
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 1/1,
                                child: Icon(Icons.logout),
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text('Log out'),
                            onTap: () {
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
        ),
```

Comment: add your code with current and expected image

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Sorry, added.

Comment: you want bigger or smaller than popup of above  image

Comment: Smaller, I just noticed the documentation has specified a minimum size for this Widget, I think due to good UI design. The height gets set from `kMinInteractiveDimension`.

Comment: you want to set height:3 on `PopupMenuItem`?

Comment: Any height to make it smaller, it does not change. I changed something else once and it worked, but it was just the outer box, not the Text and icons with it.